# How to access the object of the class where "=" operator is disabled?

Tags: c++, pointers, assignment-operator

I have a c class whose object is generated as a pointer in c++ code.

Now assignment operator is disabled in that class so how do I acess objects of that class and use it further.

Comment: C++ class. C has no classes. But I think I understood what you were asking. Look at answer below

Comment: Use members which are not the assignment operator ?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Hmmm Some task...

Do one thing create a pointer of that class in your cpp file and assign memory to it using heap allocation.

```
class *myfield = (class*)malloc(no_of_instances*sizeof(class))
```

Now use that object which is there in your header file assign myfield's address to that object(hope that is pointer)

Now it should work fine.. try and let me know..

Comment: `malloc` doesn't being the lifetime of an object of class type, unless (arguably) the object has a trivial constructor

Comment: Rather than malloc can we use new operator ? new class [memory]

Comment: Yes you can use `new`

Comment: Okay here is the thing. if you don't use malloc and go for new class [memorysize] in this particular case it wont work. 
@niyant try both and lemme know which works out well..

Comment: @MattMcNabb if you make assignment as a private member new doesn't work out .. Checked just now.... sure about it .

Comment: malloc worked for me.. 
btw is it safe to use that in c++ code ??

Comment: @spt025 I have no idea what you are trying to say

Answer (score 2):

Just because object assignment is disabled doesn't mean pointer assignment is disabled.

For example, assuming your class is `UncopyableObject` the following will work just fine.

```
UncopyableObject * obj = new UncopyableObject();
obj->doSomething();
UncopyableObject * another = obj;
```

You just need to be careful about lifetimes. You can avoid needing to care about lifetimes by using smart pointers.

```
shared_ptr<UncopyableObject> obj(new UncopyableObject());
obj->doSomething();
shared_ptr<UncopyableObject> another = obj;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply instantiate it with the constructor like so

```
YourClassName a(arguments);
```

And assigning pointers of type `YourClassName*` to each other from here on out will work just fine.